# "In orario" vs "puntuale"

Tags: word-usage

Could both "in orario" and "puntuale" be used for things and people which are on time? Examples:

- Il treno è arrivato in orario. / Il treno è arrivato puntualmente. / Il treno è puntuale.
- Sono arrivato in orario. / Sono arrivato puntualmente. / Sono puntuale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be a very short answer.

Yes, all of these sentences are perfectly correct and idiomatic.